# diagnosing a knitr error when purl produces no error

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I ran `Compile PDF` using RStudio with `knitr` on my document. I then received the error

```
Line 2333 Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I understand where this error can normally occur. However, in this instance I cannot.

1. Running the `purl`ed version of the knitr script produces no errors. That is, there are no problems with the R chunks.
2. There is no R code on line 2333 of the .Rnw file. Only pure LaTeX. Replacing the LaTeX code with a `%` produces the same error (and on the same line).

When I comment out the previous lines, I get the same error, always on the line just before the commented-out line.

What should I do to diagnose this problem?

Comment: You could try to remove as much code/text from your document as possible and add the minimal document that still reproduces the error to the question.

Comment: knitr's error reports are not always accurate when pointing to a line, probably because there is some sort of preprocessing before the actual R evaluation, so that the report you see is for a modified document. You should test the first code chunk *before* line 2333

Comment: knit the file in an _interactive_ R session via `knitr::knit()`, and use `traceback()` to find the source of the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in an inline (`\Sexpr`) function in a **subsequent** line of the knitr file.